# Django REST framework - force get request to include filter in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have 2 models in my app:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField('Content')
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')

class Blog(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField('Content')
```

I'm using ModelViewSet in my views in order to get and create objects and it works fine.

My problem is: I want to get all the comment for a specific Blog object, so I created a CommentViewSet(that inherits from ModelViewSet):

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = CommentFilter


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        try:
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise NotAcceptable(e.message)
```

I can use a filter like this `mysite.com/comment/?blog=X` in order to do it, but I want to restrict the user from requesting all comments without that filter (`mysite.com/comment/` will return all comments ever and it's bad...)

Is it possible?

Thanks!

R

Comment: Add your view in question

Comment: I added the CommentViewSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the [documentation example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) you'll need to return an [empty QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#none) instead of the full queryset in the latest return:

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
        return queryset.none()
```

Comment: OK. I think I rather raise exception instead of empty result but that is easy to change. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, is it better than creating a function in the BlogViewSet that returns all the comment of the Blog (e.g. mysite.com/Blog/4/comments)?

Comment: nop because it creates a second entry point for the same purpose.